# Spring Rest error the second time that saves Object with child properties that references the same father the second time: Already had POJO for id

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, jackson

I'm trying to update an object using REST controller in Spring 3,Jackson 4.0, using the PUT method.

We have a Container class with 4 properties one to many relationships to Container.

```
  @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@Id",scope = Container.class)
    public class Container implements Comparable, Serializable {
     private int containerId;
    .
    .
    .

    private Set<Container> containers;

    private Collection<ImagePerContainer> imageControls;

    private Collection<TextControl> textControls;

    private Collection<PromoControl> promoControls;

    private Collection<WebSource> webSourceControls;

    }
```

Each one of this Objects (childs) have a reference to Container (father), like this:

```
 @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.UUIDGenerator.class, property="@Id",scope = TextControl.class)
    public class TextControl implements Serializable {

    .
    .
    .

        private int textControlId;
        private String textControlName;
        private Container container;
    .
    .
    .

    }
```

Im trying to update the object when my angularjs app modifes the model using $resources PUT request. The first time it saves succesfully, but the second time I get a 400 response from the server, which logs this error:

```
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.bamboo.catW3.web.json.ContainerController]
Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.bamboo.catW3.domain.Container> com.bamboo.catW3.web.json.ContainerController.updateContainer(int,com.bamboo.catW3.domain.Container)]

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Already had POJO for id (java.util.UUID) [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerator$IdKey@8adc3c85] (through reference chain: com.bamboo.catW3.domain.Container["@Id"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for id (java.util.UUID) [com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerator$IdKey@8adc3c85] (through reference chain: com.bamboo.catW3.domain.Container["@Id"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
```

If I update another Container it works also the first time, but if I modified again and try to update it gives me the same 400 error. It doesn't even enter the controller. If I restart the server, then it lets me update the object one time, and it stops working again.

Why does it work the first time only ?  How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and just found this link :

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/499

It said that it was a bug in jackson 2.4.0 that was fixed in 2.4.1 and later.

Just update your jackson library to the latest stable release.