# Serializing Already had POJO for id (java.lang.String)

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I have two entities i serialized and send to client using spring framework 4.2.5 + jacksonjson 2.7.5. My entities are the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entrada")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idEntrada")
public class EntradaTest implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id_entrada", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String idEntrada;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 5)
private String codigo;

private Integer recibidos;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idEmpleado", scope = Empleado.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_pesador_bruto")
private Empleado pesadorBruto;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "dEmpleado", scope = Empleado.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_pesador_tara")
private Empleado pesadorTara;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idEmpleado", scope = Empleado.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_representante_bruto")
private Empleado representanteBruto;

@ManyToOne
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "idEmpleado", scope = Empleado.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_representante_tara")
private Empleado representanteTara;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_oficina", nullable = false)
private Entidad oficina;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "empleado")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idEmpleado", scope = Empleado.class)
class Empleadoest implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id_empleado", unique = true, nullable = false)
private String idEmpleado;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 125)
private String nombre;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pesadorBruto")
private Set<Entrada> entradasPesadorBruto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pesadorTara")
private Set<Entrada> entradasPesadorTara;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "representanteBruto")
private Set<Entrada> entradasRepresentanteBruto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "representanteTara")
private Set<Entrada> entradasRepresentanteTara;
}
```

My REST service end points are

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/entradas/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Entrada> getEntrada(@PathVariable("id") String idEntrada) {
Entrada entrada = entradaService.get(idEntrada);
if (entrada == null) {
return new ResponseEntity<Entrada>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
return new ResponseEntity<Entrada>(entrada, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/entradas/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Void> createEntrada(@RequestBody Entrada entrada, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {

entradaService.save(entrada);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/entradas/{id}").buildAndExpand(entrada.getIdEntrada()).toUri());
return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The serialized data I send to the client looks like:

```
{
"idEntrada": "e375ecf9-dabd-4c76-8813-0679818f9590",
"codigo": "378-2",
"recibidos": 0,
"pesadorBruto": "0c23c490-a54a-495d-9447-dc6227520646",
"pesadorTara": "874dfe26-11cb-48e4-916e-bf8a83187dcb",
"representanteBruto": "5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",
"representanteTara": "5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",
"oficina": {
"idEntidad": "f3964add-3ae8-4392-bafc-cffb9643ec15",
"nombre": "O.P.C.",
},
}
```

But when i try to send data back to the server as following to create a new entity

```
{
"idEntrada":"e375ecf9-dabd-4c76-8813-0679818f9590",
"codigo":"378-2",
"pesadorBruto":{
"idEmpleado":"0c23c490-a54a-495d-9447-dc6227520646",
"nombre":"J. CABRERA",
},
"pesadorTara":{
"idEmpleado":"874dfe26-11cb-48e4-916e-bf8a83187dcb",
"nombre":"L. A. DELGADO",
},
"representanteBruto":{
"idEmpleado":"5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",
"nombre":"C. MARQUEZ",
},
"representanteTara":{
"idEmpleado":"5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",
"nombre":"C. MARQUEZ",
},
"oficina":{
"idEntidad":"f3964add-3ae8-4392-bafc-cffb9643ec15",
"nombre":"O.P.C.",
},
}
```

Jackson fails:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
Could not read document: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.String)
[[ObjectId: key=5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f,
type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator,
scope=lt.ciader.model.Empleado]]
(through reference chain: lt.ciader.model.Entrada["representanteTara"]->lt.ciader.model.Empleado["idEmpleado"]);
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Already had POJO for id (java.lang.String)
[[ObjectId: key=5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f,
type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator,
scope=lt.ciader.model.Empleado]]
(through reference chain: lt.ciader.model.Entrada["representanteTara"]->lt.ciader.model.Empleado["idEmpleado"])
```

I know that representanteTara is the same sa representateBruto but it can be the same employment acoording to my model, even pesadorTara and PesadorBruto too.

When i send data with differents empleados my service get data and serialized it without problems.
I googled to find a solution but i can't find an answer that help me. I review:

[JsonMappingException: Already had POJO for id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422838/jsonmappingexception-already-had-pojo-for-id)

[Jackson Already had POJO for id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36506536/jackson-already-had-pojo-for-id)

[Spring Rest error the second time that saves Object with child properties that references the same father the second time: Already had POJO for id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476808/spring-rest-error-the-second-time-that-saves-object-with-child-properties-that-r)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/TSloBi1C_qk

https://github.com/edwinquaihoi/jsonidentitymanytomany/issues/1

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/266

What i doing wrong. How can I solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many test I found a solution. The problem is that Jackson fails becouse the same entity is present two times. The solution is send only the plain ID in the secon instance, not wrapped in object:

```
{
"idEntrada":"e375ecf9-dabd-4c76-8813-0679818f9590",
"codigo":"378-2",
"pesadorBruto":{
"idEmpleado":"0c23c490-a54a-495d-9447-dc6227520646",
"nombre":"J. CABRERA",
},
"pesadorTara":{
"idEmpleado":"874dfe26-11cb-48e4-916e-bf8a83187dcb",
"nombre":"L. A. DELGADO",
},
"representanteBruto":{
"idEmpleado":"5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",
"nombre":"C. MARQUEZ",
},
```

> `"representanteTara": "5fb567af-805a-40dc-84bc-8f6038d8cd2f",`

```
"oficina":{
"idEntidad":"f3964add-3ae8-4392-bafc-cffb9643ec15",
"nombre":"O.P.C.",
},
}
```